# shopping cart wont pick up the product ID

Tags: php, html, database, cart, product

shop.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My first Web page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/final_index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
            <div class="span1"> </div>
            <header>
                <img id="banner" src="images/safc.banner.PNG" alt="banner">
            </header>

        </div>

        <div class="banner1">

        </div>
<br />
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a class="brand" href="#">Sunderland</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="final_index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="shop.php">Shop</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="login.php">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="reg.php">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="protect.php">Protected Page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="admin.php">Admin</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="login1">
            <div id="login1"

            <div class="grid20"> 



<a href="shop.php?cat=Clothes">Clothes</a>
<a href="shop.php?cat=Accessories">Accessories</a>

<div class="shop2"

<div class="grid20"

<div id="s"

</br>

        <?php
             $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','c3364964','goldie123','c3364964');
        $cat = $_GET ['cat'];

echo $cat. " available displayed here";

?>

<?php

print "<table border=3px cellpadding=12px >";

print "<th>ProductID</th>";

print "<th>Name</ th>";

print "<th>Price</ th>";

print "<th>Image</ th>";

print "<th>Add to cart</ th>";

if ($cat == 'Clothes'){

$query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Type = 'Clothes' ORDER BY ProductPrice DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

{

echo " <tr>";

echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['ProductPrice'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . '<img width=50px height=50px src="./images/' . $row['ProductImage'] . '"  />' . "</td>";

echo "<td><a href=\"cart.php?action=add&id=$ID\">Add To Cart</a></td>";
//echo "<td>" . '<a href="AmendProduct.php?id='. $row['ID'].'">Amend</a>' . "</td>";

//echo "<td>" . '<a href="DeleteProduct.php?id='. $row['ID'].'">Delete</a>' . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

}

print "</table>";

}

else {

$query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Type = 'Accessories' ORDER BY ProductPrice";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

{

echo " <tr>";

echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['ProductPrice'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . '<img width=50px height=50px src="./images/' . $row['ProductImage'] . '" />' . "</td>";

echo "<td><a href=\"cart.php?action=add&id=$product_id\">Add To Cart</a></td>";

//echo "<td>" . '<a href="AmendProduct.php?id='. $row['ID'].'">Amend</a>' . "</td>";

//echo "<td>" . '<a href="DeleteProduct.php?id='. $row['ID'].'">Delete</a>' . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

}

print "</table>";

}


?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div><!-- /#content-wrapper -->

<!-- footer row -->




            </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
    </html>
```

cart.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="description" content="PHP Shopping Cart Using Sessions" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="shopping cart tutorial, shopping cart, php, sessions" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/style/style.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Cart</title>


<?php
include 'connected.php';
?>


</head>
<body>


<?php

$ID = $_GET[ID];     //the product id from the URL 
$action     = $_GET[action]; //the action from the URL 

//if there is an product_id and that product_id doesn't exist display an error         message
if($ID && !productExists($ID)) {
    die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
}

switch($action) {   //decide what to do 

    case "add":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$ID]++; //add one to the quantity of the product     with id $product_id 
    break;

    case "remove":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$ID]--; //remove one from the quantity of the     product with id $product_id 
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$ID] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$ID]); //if     the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will     show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items. 
    break;

    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart']); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the     cart. 
    break;

}

?>


<?php   

if($_SESSION['cart']) { //if the cart isn't empty
    //show the cart

    echo "<table border=\"1\" padding=\"3\" width=\"40%\">";    //format     the cart using a HTML table

        //iterate through the cart, the $product_id is the key and     $quantity is the value
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $ID => $quantity) {    

            //get the name, description and price from the database -     this will depend on your database implementation.
            //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted     into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
            $query = sprintf("SELECT  ProductName,  ProductPrice, FROM     Produts WHERE ID = %d;",
                            $ID); 

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            //Only display the row if there is a product (though there     should always be as we have already checked)
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                list($ProductName, $ProductPrice) =     mysqli_fetch_row($result);

                $line_cost = $ProductPrice * $quantity;         //work out the line cost
                $total = $total + $line_cost;               //add to the total cost

                echo "<tr>";
                    //show this information in table cells
                    echo "<td align=\"center\">$name</td>";
                    //along with a 'remove' link next to the     quantity - which links to this page, but with an action of remove, and the id of the current product
                    echo "<td align=\"center\">$quantity <a     href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=remove&id=$product_id\">X</a></td>";
                    echo "<td     align=\"center\">$line_cost</td>";

                echo "</tr>";

            } else 
                echo "No results";

        }

        //show the total
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"right\">Total</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"right\">$total</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        //show the empty cart link - which links to this page, but with an     action of empty. A simple bit of javascript in the onlick event of the link asks the user for confirmation
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan=\"3\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=empty\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\">Empty Cart</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";       
    echo "</table>";



}else{
    //otherwise tell the user they have no items in their cart
    echo "You have no items in your shopping cart.";

}

//function to check if a product exists
function productExists($ID) {
        //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id = %d;",
                        $ID); 

        return mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($sql)) > 0;
}
?>

<a href="shop.php">Continue Shopping</a>
```

this page should when i i find an item that i would like to add to cart i would click add to cart then it bring up the cart with the item that i have selected in it however when i click add to cart it brings up the cart but does not have the item that i have selected in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think line 115 and 148 in shop.php should be

```
115: echo "<td><a href=\"cart.php?action=add&id=".$row['ID']."\">Add To Cart</a></td>";
148: echo "<td><a href=\"cart.php?action=add&id=".$row['ID']."\">Add To Cart</a></td>";
```

Comment: cheers this has solved one problem now when i hover over the item it selects the right id but still nothing come up in cart

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check.

Ensure the column name in your 'Products' table is 'ID' and not 'id'
(Its rare to have capitalised column names).

```
$row['ID'] -> $ row['id']
```

Secondly i dont think cart.php is picking up your id because.

```
cart.php?action=add&id=$ID
```

uses lower case 'id' and

```
$ID = $_GET[ID];     //the product id from the URL 
$action     = $_GET[action]; //the action from the URL
```

users uppercase 'ID'. So change to:

```
$ID = $_GET["id"];
$action = $_GET["action"];
```

echo out $ID and $action on cart.php to ensure they are being picked up from the url.

Hope this helps, fellow Leeds Met Student.

EDIT:
 
Looking at CygnusH33L answer, ensure your link to cart.php is changed so you use $row['ID'].
Or define $ID.

```
<a href=\"cart.php?action=add&id=".$row['ID']."\">
or
$ID = $row['ID'];
```

Comment: have changed them all to uppercase ID and tried an echo it does pick up the correct product but still does not put them into cart

Comment: this could be due to the fact your are trying to increment an undefined session when item is added to cart for the first time.
I would also do a "print_r($_SESSION['cart']);" to see exactly what is stored in there. Do this after your switch.